# GLFW cannot compile without "glu.h" and "windows.h"

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, game-engine, glfw

I want to create a game engine, but my graphics subsystem will not compile without `<GL/glu.h>` and `<windows.h>`.

1. Compiling `Graphics.cpp` with only `<GLFW/glfw3.h>`, without both headers will print the error on `Graphics.cpp`, `'gluErrorString' was not declared in this scope`.
2. Compiling `Graphics.cpp` with `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` AND '', without `<windows.h>` will print the error on `glu.h`, `c:\mingw\include\gl\glu.h|225|error: 'WINGDIAPI' does not name a type`. Some workaround I found is to include also the `<windows.h>` in `Graphics.cpp`.
3. Compiling `Graphics.cpp` with `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` AND '' AND `<windows.h>` returns no error. The problem is that this program is not cross-platform isn't it?

As stated in [GLFW build guide](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/build_guide.html) in the `Including the GLFW header file` section; One does not need to include `windows.h` and OpenGL header files, since GLFW header already included these. So I am trying to follow the guide or best practice, and trying to make my game engine cross-platform.

Followings are my linker options in CodeBlock,

```
-lglfw3
-lOpenGL32
-lglu32
-lgdi32
```

Comment: GLU is outdated. It's no longer part of modern OpenGL. That's why GLFW doesn't include it.

Comment: "*my graphics subsystem will not compile without <GL/glu.h> and <windows.h>.*" That's because your graphics subsystem is *using* stuff from those headers. This is not GLFW's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I only have to write `GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU` in CodeBlock's compiler settings in the `#defines` section.

Source: [Building GLFW program, by Sugih Jamin](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~sugih/courses/eecs487/glut-howto/glfw/)